# Binding to a property in a ViewModel from a ResourceDirectory

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, idataerrorinfo

I have an email address `TextBox`, so the user can input their email. I have implemented the MVVM pattern with the `IDataErrorInfo` interface to display errors.

The `ViewModel` has a property called `IsValiedEmailAddress`, which checks to see if the email address is a valid email format:

```
/// Check to see if email if valid
#region
public bool IsValidEmailAddress
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            MailAddress address = new MailAddress(EmailAddress);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("IsValidEmailAddress");
    }
}
#endregion
```

As you can see in the image the logic and the `IDataErrorInfo` is working fine as an error is being displayed.

What I want to do is to disable the button when there is an invalid email address. 
I have tried binding the property to the button, however, it doesn't work as I've used a `ResourceDirectory` to create the style of the button and other validation to prevent the button being pressed, such as the email being empty.

```
<ResourceDirectory>
<!-- OTHER CODE EMITTED SUCH AS STYLING  -->
    <Style>
    <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=EmailAddressTextBox, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsValidEmailAddress, ElementName=EmailAddressTextBox}" >
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>

            </Style.Triggers>
    </Style
</ResourceDirectory>
```

How can I prevent the submit button being pressed unless the user has inserted a correctly formatted email address

This is what I have in the resource directory so far to bind the `IsValidEmailAddress` to the button. I'm unsure what is wrong with it.

```
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsValidEmailAddress, ElementName=EmailAddressTextBox}" >
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            </DataTrigger>
```

[image]

Comment: No my resource directory is located in a separate folder called Styles, then its called "Buttons.xaml". I have then in the App.xaml file created a ResourceDictonary.MergedDictionaries to access them throughout the app.

Comment: Personally I don't recommend using ResourceDictionaries outside of the View layer.  Your ViewModel shouldn't be looking upwards towards the View and. View can reach the Resources directly.  If you want to bind to resources then I personally suggest using something simple like an enum in the ViewModel and changing the View resource from that binding.  Example: Styles.StyleA might bean use StylesAResourceDictionary or something of that nature.

Comment: @javacoder123 Can you add the XAML code for your TextBox?